# REACT with ts - checking props is null in tsx.view

Tags: reactjs

The props -

```
interface Props {
  readonly prices: IPrices | null;
  readonly pricesChangeHandler: (value: IPrices | null) => void;
}
```

What I want to check -

```
<p 
  className={classes['innerContainer__text']}>
  {props.prices?.BTCUSD}
</p>
```

I want to display something if the `props.prices?.BTCUSD` is null and display the value if it's now null

Comment: {props.prices?.BTCUSD === null ? 'show something' : 'or others'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OR operator

```
<p 
  className={classes['innerContainer__text']}>
  {props.prices?.BTCUSD || "your other value"}
</p>
```